# Sort Gridview or IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ilist

Here is code which i can edit only:

```
ICCModelController ctrl = ControllerGettersFactory.ModelControllerGetters().CCModelController;
IList list = ctrl.SearchCareersWithCategories(null, 0, DateTime.Today);

CareerGrid.DataSource = list;
CareerGrid.DataBind();
```

Current 'CareerGrid' grid view result in Ascending order with respect of column 'Date'.
where as i want it in Descending order.

Answer (score 1):

```
CareerGrid.DataSource = list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date);
CareerGrid.DataBind();
```

or, if it's already sorted by date

```
CareerGrid.DataSource = list.Reverse();
CareerGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Ilist is used, which is not supported Reverse()
'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'Reverse' and no extension method 'Reverse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)